# install4j - option to modify the required disk space

Tags: install4j

Is there any way to modify the required disk space option in install4j?

In my particular use case I have some optional/downloadable components which are actually archives and get extracted in the installation location if selected. Unfortunately I can't just set the contents of the archives themselves as optional components instead of the archives.

The installer shows the disk space required for the base install and the selected components, but I need to update that so the optional components get added twice (once for the zip which gets downloaded and a second time for the actual space used when extracted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Install files" action has an "Installation size calculator" property where you can modify the default size.

Answer (score 0):

For the disk space check, add a "Run script" action to the "Startup" node of your installer and set its script to

```java
if (SystemInfo.getFreeDiskSpace(context.getInstallationDirectory()) < 2000000000) {
    Util.showErrorMessage("You need at least 2 GB of free memory");
    return false;
}
return true;
```

Then, set the "Failure strategy" property of the action to "Quit on failure":

[image]

Comment: That doesn't really help, as I don't want to quit on failure. What I need is to be able to dynamically update the Required disk space: on the Select Destination Directory screen based on what optional components the user selects. I could add this check as a validation expression script during the Install location step and throw an error to the user, but this isn't as nice as the installer actually telling the user how much space it needs.

Comment: Hmm.. It's been ssome time since I worked with install4j myself.. Not sure if there's a way to get the selected components and sum up their sizes at that point.